# Automating with Puppet on GCE without `gcutil` (deprecated)

Tags: puppet, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am trying to automate an instance using Puppet in Google cloud but unfortunately got an error. I had done this earlier with your help but the settings seems to be changed.

```
ERROR: 'gcutil' has been deprecated and is no longer part of Cloud SDK distribution.
ERROR: Please use 'gcloud compute' instead.
```

Comment: Just switch to `gcloud compute` command group

Comment: I have noticed commands are bit changed. How to implement in puppet ?? as I am automating from puppet manifest.

Comment: I'm not familiar with puppet, but there are direct equivalencies for most `gcutil` commands; take a look at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/transition-gcloud-gcutil

Comment: As an alternative, can you use the Puppet module instead of the `gcutil` command line tool? See [Puppet forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/gce_compute) and [GitHub](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-gce_compute) for more info.

Comment: @MishaBrukman yes... I am using the same module to launch the instance. Suddenly it stopped working (same configuration, same manifest).

Comment: @user3933150 — the current version of the Puppet module for GCE on GitHub uses `gcloud`, not `gcutil` so maybe just update it so it should work? `gcutil` was deprecated a while ago, maybe it just no longer appears in new GCE VM images? What is the version of GCE VM image you're using?

Comment: @user3933150 — [puppetlabs/gce_compute](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/gce_compute/readme) 1.0.0 was just released with this fix; please update your installation.

Answer (score 0):

The change from `gcutil` to `gcloud` was [merged recently](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-gce_compute/pull/35) on GitHub on 21 July 2015 and released in [puppetlabs/gce_compute](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/gce_compute/readme) 1.0.0 on 29 July 2015, so you should upgrade to get this change.

Comment: Thanks.. I will give it a try.